# How to set bootstrap active tab on refresh in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating tabs as:

```
 <tabset class="content-tabset no-margin">
<tab ng-repeat="t in t.values" heading="{{t.name}}" active="t.active">
  //other stuff
</tab>
</tabset>
```

Now within this other stuff I also have button which when clicks updates the row and refreshes that part. When the refresh happens it also resets the tab I am currently on.
So if I am tab two and click on the button, the panel refreshes and I come back on tab 1. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Can you post the code that is called when the button is pressed?

Comment: What is `t.active` value? ID of tab or name?

Comment: @Jonny sorry the code is long so I cant post the code here. I am calling angular.extend that refreshes my different items that are bind on my page.

Comment: @rene t.active is true or false

Comment: Okay. Edited my answer, so it will be `boolean`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `localStorage`. Set it on selecting tab. To get boolean value of active state for current tab use `ng-init`.

```
<tabset class="content-tabset no-margin">
  <tab 
    ng-repeat="t in t.values" 
    heading="{{t.name}}" 
    ng-init="isActive = isActiveTab(t.name, $index)"
    active="isActive"
    select="setActiveTab(t.name)">
    //other stuff
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

And in your controller

```
$scope.setActiveTab = function( activeTab ){
    localStorage.setItem("activeTab", activeTab);
};

$scope.getActiveTab = function(){
    return localStorage.getItem("activeTab");
};

$scope.isActiveTab = function( tabName, index ){
    var activeTab = $scope.getActiveTab();
    return ( activeTab === tabName || ( activeTab === null && $index === 0 ) );
};
```

NOTE: Since your `t` has no unique ID for tabs, names should be unique to detect active tab correctly.

See example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ReneKorss/4q0e57f3/).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you do a refresh the local/scope variables runs out of scope. So the way out to solve this is using JavaScript's **Session Storage/ Local Storage**.

Session storage will run out of scope once you close the browser while local storage will persist value till window and browser lifetimes.

**Inside controller:**

```
$scope.selTab = sessionStorage.tabName; //On refresh it will fetch value from session storage

$scope.onClickTab = function(tabName){ //On click it will set the sessionStorage
    $scope.selTab = tabName;
    sessionStorage.tabName = tabName;
}
```

**Inside HTML** *must refer your controller*

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12{{active}}">
  <li ng-class ="{active:selTab=='tab1'}"><a href="#/tab1" ng-click="onClickTab('tab1')">Tab3</a></li>
  <li ng-class ="{active:selTab=='tab3'}"><a href="#/tab3" ng-click="onClickTab('tab3')">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package `ui-router-tabs`. Follow the link https://github.com/rpocklin/ui-router-tabs. Easy to use and gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by using **Local Storage**

**Inside HTML:**

```
            <ul class="nav">
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="goToManageUsers('manageUser')" ng-class="{'active': selectedTab == 'manageUser'}">
                        <i class="lnr lnr-home"></i>
                        <span>Manage User</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="goToManageRequest('manageImage')" ng-class="{'active': selectedTab == 'manageImage'}">
                        <i class="lnr lnr-home"></i>
                        <span>Manage Image</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

**Inside Controller:**

```
$scope.selectedTab = localStorage.getItem('getActive');
$scope.goToManageUsers = function (user) {
    $scope.selectedTab = user;
    localStorage.setItem('getActive', user);

}
$scope.goToManageRequest = function (image) {
    $scope.selectedTab = image;
    localStorage.setItem('getActive', image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this same thing in Angular 2+, you also use LocalStorage.  Something like this (I used ng-bootstrap to enable Bootstrap tabs):

*HTML:*

```
<ngb-tabset class="nav-fill" (tabChange)="tabChange($event)" [activeId]="activeTabId">
    <ngb-tab title="Tab 1" id="tab1">
        ...
    </ngb-tab>
    <ngb-tab title="Tab 2" id="tab2">
        ...
    </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

*.ts:*

```
import {NgbTabChangeEvent} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
... other imports

export class MyComponent {

    activeTabId: string;

    constructor() {
        this.activeTabId = localStorage.getItem("activeTab");
    }

    tabChange($event: NgbTabChangeEvent) {
        localStorage.setItem("activeTab", $event.nextId);
    }
}
```